# Can't show data on the page

Tags: php, html, mysql

So, I recently moved a database from one host to another, and also had to move the HTML and php pages used to display the data, and for some reason it simply wouldn't display the data on the page. I know my php page is connecting to the database because when I use a simple `if` statement in the `php` page, it does display the correct data.
The website worked properly on the previous server and database host.

My HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Olympic Scores</title>
    <link href="../favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
    <link href="css/tasks.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">label.error { 
            float: none; color: red; padding-left: 0.5em; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align: top; 
        }
    </style>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#medalValues").validate();
            });
        </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="wrapper">
<div class="header_style">
<h1><a href="link"><strong>Back to </strong>Portfolio</a></h1>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<header>
<h1>Olympics<span> - London 2012</span></h1>

<h2>Medals Table</h2>

<h2></h2>
</header>

<div class="image_body">
<div class="image_effect" id="image_click">
<p>Copyright free image of a 2004 Olympics Gold Medal</p>

<p>2004 Olympics - Athens</p>
</div>
<span class="image_note">Keep clicked to show image</span></div>

<div class="content" id="home_page">
<p class="titles">Please assign the weight of the Gold Medals, Silver Medals and Bronze Medals:</p>

<p>(Only numbers are allowed)</p>

<nav>
<div>
<form id="medalValues" method="get"><label class="gold_label" for="gold_value">Gold Medals:</label> <input id="gold_value" name="gold_value" required="required" type="number" value="3" /> <label class="silver_label" for="silver_value">Silver Medals:</label> <input id="silver_value" name="silver_value" required="required" type="number" value="2" /> <label class="bronze_label" for="bronze_value">Bronze Medals:</label> <input id="bronze_value" name="bronze_value" required="required" type="number" value="1" /><br />
<p>Calculate Score Based on</p>
<br />
<label for="medals_only">Medals Only</label> <input id="medals_only" name="radio_button" onclick="no_medals_formula();" required="required" type="radio" value="opt1" /> <!--OnClick runs the function to display the formula used--> <label for="population">Population</label> <input id="population" name="radio_button" onclick="population_formula();" required="required" type="radio" value="opt2" /> <!--OnClick runs the function to display the formula used--> <label for="gdp">GDP</label> <input id="gdp" name="radio_button" onclick="gdp_formula();" required="required" type="radio" value="opt3" /> <!--OnClick runs the function to display the formula used--> <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br />
<p id="formula_used"></p>


<table id="score_results">
</table>
</form>
</div>
<script>
                            //When document is ready
                            $(function() {

                                //Handles form submission
                                $('#medalValues').submit(function() {

                                    var gold_value, silver_value, bronze_value, medals_only, population, gdp;

                                    //Gets the values from the weight inputs, checks which radio is checked
                                    gold_value = $("#gold_value").val();
                                    silver_value = $("#silver_value").val();
                                    bronze_value = $("#bronze_value").val();
                                    medals_only = $("#medals_only").is(':checked');
                                    gdp = $("#gdp").is(':checked');
                                    population = $("#population").is(':checked');

                                    getResults( gold_value, silver_value, bronze_value, medals_only, population, gdp );

                                    //Stops the form submitting
                                    return false;
                                });

                            });

                            function getResults ( gold_value, silver_value, bronze_value, medals_only, population, gdp ) {

                                $.get('view.php', {gold_value: gold_value, silver_value: silver_value, bronze_value: bronze_value, medals_only: medals_only, population: population, gdp: gdp} ,  function(data) {
                                    postResults(data);
                                });
                            }

                            function postResults (data) {

                                //Turns the string into json
                                var json = $.parseJSON(data);

                                //Inputs the table headings for the html table
                                var output = "<colgroup><col class=oce-first /><col class=oce-second /><col class=oce-third /><col class=oce-fourth /><col class=oce-fifth /></colgroup><tr><th class=rank_header scope=col>Rank</th><th class=rank_country scope=col>Country Name</th><th class=score_header scope=col>Score</th><th class=gdp_header scope=col>GDP</th><th class=population_header scope=col>Population</th>";

                                for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

                                    //Loops through and posts them into a html table
                                    output+= "<tr class=spacing>"
                                    output+= "<td id=selected_rank>" + (i+1) + "</td>"
                                    output+= "<td>" + json[i].country + "</td>"
                                    output+= "<td id=selected_score>" + json[i].score + "</td>"
                                    output+= "<td>" + json[i].gdp + "</td>"
                                    output+= "<td>" + json[i].population + "</td>"
                                    output+= "</tr>"
                                }

                            // Push the output html into the results table
                            $("#score_results").html(output);
                            }
                        </script></nav>
</div>

<div class="footer_style">
<h1><strong>Part of my </strong>Portfolio</h1>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<!--Functions to update the element wihth id=formula_used to change the text depending on which radio button the user selected--><script>
                    function no_medals_formula() {
                        document.getElementById("formula_used").innerHTML="The Formula used was: (gold * $gold_value) + (silver * $silver_value) + (bronze * $bronze_value) <br/>Rounded to 2 d.p";
                    }
                    function population_formula() {
                        document.getElementById("formula_used").innerHTML="The Formula used was: ((gold * $gold_value) + (silver * $silver_value) + (bronze * $bronze_value)) / (population / Million) <br/>Rounded to 2 d.p";
                    }
                    function gdp_formula() {
                        document.getElementById("formula_used").innerHTML="The Formula used was: ((gold * $gold_value) + (silver * $silver_value) + (bronze * $bronze_value)) / (gdp / 10 Billion) <br/>Rounded to 2 d.p";
                    }
                </script></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my php code is:

```
<?php

require_once 'MDB2.php'

$hostname="hostname.hostedresource.com";
$username="username";
$password="password";
$dbname="dbname";
$usertable="usertable";
$yourfield = "ISO_id";

mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) or die ("<html><script language='JavaScript'>alert('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.'),history.go(-1)</script></html>");
mysql_select_db($dbname);

# Check If Record Exists
$dsn = "mysql://$username:$password@$hostname/$dbname"; 

$db =& MDB2::connect($dsn); 
if(PEAR::isError($db)){ 
    die($db->getMessage());
}

$db->setFetchMode(MDB2_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);

//Gets the values the user assigned to Gold, Silver and Bronze
    $gold_value = $_GET["gold_value"];
    $silver_value = $_GET["silver_value"];
    $bronze_value = $_GET["bronze_value"];
    $medals_only = $_GET["medals_only"];
    $population = $_GET["population"];
    $gdp = $_GET["gdp"];

//If statements that choose which sql statement to run.
//sql statement that gets run when user selects to calculate score without using population or gdp, orders it by score, and stops after reaching 10.

if ($medals_only == 'true') {
    $sql="SELECT gold, silver, bronze, gdp, population, country_name, ROUND(((gold * $gold_value) + (silver * $silver_value) + (bronze * $bronze_value)),2) as score
    FROM $usertable
    ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0,10";
//sql statement that gets run when user selects to calculate score witH population, orders it by score, and stops after reaching 10.
}
else if($population == 'true'){ 
    $sql="SELECT gold, silver, bronze, gdp, population, country_name, ROUND(((gold * $gold_value) + (silver * $silver_value) + (bronze * $bronze_value)) / (population / 1000000),2) as score 
    FROM $usertable
    ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0,10";
//sql statement that gets run when user selects to calculate score with gdp, orders it by score, and stops after reaching 10.
}
else if($gdp == 'true'){ 
    $sql="SELECT gold, silver, bronze, gdp, population, country_name, ROUND(((gold * $gold_value) + (silver * $silver_value) + (bronze * $bronze_value)) / (gdp / 10000000000),2) as score 
    FROM $usertable
    ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0,10";
}   

$res =& $db->query($sql);
if(PEAR::isError($res)){
        die($res->getMessage());
}

echo json_encode($res->fetchAll() );    

?>
```

When I go directly to the php `page-view.php` I get the error

> MDB2 Error: unknown error

Comment: Add this after the first php tag ( `<?php` ) for debugging:  `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);` -- Do you get any errors? in php or browser console?

Comment: Have you created the database/tables in the new server?

Comment: Yes, I have created the database and table in the new server. I tested the connection with   `if($result)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$name = $row["$yourfield"];
echo "Name: ".$name."<br>";
}
}` in the php page which resulted in a big list of Name: `data from table`

Comment: Great, and about my first question?

Comment: @Sergio I added the error reporting. When I go to the html page and run it again, nothing happens like before. When I go to the php page I get this: `Warning: require_once(MDB2.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/88/11140488/html/olympics/view.php on line 7

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'MDB2.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /home/content/88/11140488/html/olympics/view.php on line 7`

Comment: Try this: `$the_file="MDB2.php"; require_once($the_file);` And check where the file is (if same directory or above/under) and change the path until you get it.

Comment: @Sergio so, I just change `$the_file` to `$view.php` as both html and php files are in the same folder?

Comment: The error reporting is helping you. Your problem is including your MDB2.php file. Is `MDB2.php` in the `olympics/` directory? Try my code to do the require once. Replace your `require_once 'MDB2.php'` with this: `$the_file="MDB2.php"; require_once($the_file);`

Comment: And check if view.php and MDB2.php are in the same folder

Comment: @Sergio There is no `MDB2.php` in the olympics directory. But it wasn't in the folder on the previous server either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35239/discussion-between-d-shah-and-sergio)

Comment: One last thing, you might want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MDB2

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once 'MDB2.php'
```

Should be:

```
require_once('MDB2.php');
```

There is no ";" and the function syntax is wrong. This is what I have noticed so far, there may be another problem with where MDB2.php is located, as you will need to include the parent directories that MDB2.php resides in.